# "No longer needed" comment flag for merged question declined

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, flagging

I raised a "no longer needed" flag on a comment in [Where do Bulgarians originate from?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61918/where-do-bulgarians-originate-from)

The comment suggested a duplicate question, specifically [What were the origins of the Bulgarian people?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26889/what-were-the-origins-of-the-bulgarian-people).

However, the proposed duplicate question **had already been merged** with the very question it was proposed to be a duplicate of. There are no answers in the proposed duplicate and clicking on the "merged" link leads you right back to the first one.

The comment really ***isn't*** needed anymore and will just confuse future readers. Please delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the comment.

Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

I wasn't the mod who declined your flag, but I believe it should have been marked helpful.